# Some select behavior futures in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I really don't understand why 3 select queries have different behavior although 2nd and 3rd are sense similar. 2nd query with error and 3rd query without error

**first query - 1 join with aliased attributes - OK**

```sql
SELECT 
    id as bet_slip_id,
    placed,
    settled,
    status,
    fk_user as user_id,
    tax_system_id,
    tax_system_name,
    fk_agent as agent_id
FROM
    stage.bet_slip
ANY LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id as tax_system_id,
        name as tax_system_name
    FROM stage.tax_system
            ) ts
   ON fk_tax_system = ts.tax_system_id
WHERE
    settled < '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
    AND settled >= '2019-04-16 00:00:00'
limit $limit
```

**second query - 2 joins with aliased attributes - Error**

```sql
SELECT 
    id as bet_slip_id,
    placed,
    settled,
    status,
    fk_user as user_id,
    tax_system_id,
    tax_system_name,
    leg_bonus_scheme_id,
    leg_bonus_scheme_name,
    fk_agent as agent_id
FROM
    stage.bet_slip
ANY LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id as tax_system_id,
        name as tax_system_name
    FROM stage.tax_system
            ) ts
   ON fk_tax_system = ts.tax_system_id
ANY LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id as leg_bonus_scheme_id,
        name as leg_bonus_scheme_name
    FROM stage.leg_bonus_scheme
            ) ls
   ON fk_leg_bonus_scheme = ls.leg_bonus_scheme_id       
WHERE
    settled < '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
    AND settled >= '2019-04-16 00:00:00'
limit $limit
```

**third query - 2 joins with another aliased attributes - OK**

```sql
SELECT 
    id as bet_slip_id,
    placed,
    settled,
    status,
    fk_user as user_id,
    fk_tax_system as tax_system_id,
    tax_system_name,
    leg_bonus_scheme_id,
    leg_bonus_scheme_name,
    fk_agent as agent_id
FROM
    stage.bet_slip
ANY LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id as fk_tax_system,
        name as tax_system_name
    FROM stage.tax_system
            ) ts
   ON fk_tax_system = ts.fk_tax_system  
ANY LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id as leg_bonus_scheme_id,
        name as leg_bonus_scheme_name
    FROM stage.leg_bonus_scheme
            ) ls
   ON fk_leg_bonus_scheme = ls.leg_bonus_scheme_id       
WHERE
    settled < '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
    AND settled >= '2019-04-16 00:00:00'
limit $limit
```

Error as result 2nd query:

> Code: 47, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Unknown identifier:
>   tax_system_id, context: query: 'SELECT id AS bet_slip_id, placed,
>   settled, status, fk_user AS user_id, tax_system_id, tax_system_name,
>   leg_bonus_scheme_id, leg_bonus_scheme_name, fk_agent AS agent_id FROM
>   (SELECT * FROM stage.bet_slip  ANY LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS
>   tax_system_id, name AS tax_system_name FROM stage.tax_system ) AS ts
>   ON fk_tax_system = `--ts.tax_system_id`)  ANY LEFT JOIN (SELECT id AS
>   leg_bonus_scheme_id, name AS leg_bonus_scheme_name FROM
>   stage.leg_bonus_scheme ) AS ls ON fk_leg_bonus_scheme =
>   leg_bonus_scheme_id WHERE (settled < '2019-05-01 00:00:00') AND
>   (settled >= '2019-04-16 00:00:00') LIMIT 100000' required_names:
>   'fk_leg_bonus_scheme''fk_agent'/'agent_id''leg_bonus_scheme_id''placed''id'/'bet_slip_id''settled''leg_bonus_scheme_name''status''tax_system_name''fk_user'/'user_id''tax_system_id'
>   source_tables: 'ls' table_aliases: 'ls' complex_aliases:
>   masked_columns: array_join_columns: source_columns: 'id' 'fk_user'
>   'placed' 'status' 'settled' 'fk_agent' 'fk_leg_bonus_scheme'
>   'tax_system_name'  (version 19.5.3.8 (official build))

Comment: did you try use
SELECT ts.tax_system_id ?

Comment: have stage.leg_bonus_scheme field tax_system_id ?

Comment: It strange and it seems like a little bag, but adding prefix ts.tax_system_id was helped. I can't see clear logic, because same joined attribute leg_bonus_scheme_id not needed prefix for identifying. And in all samples all used attribute aliased different names for clear understanding. And also tax_system_id not in stage.leg_bonus_scheme too.